# Synchronizing a crowd in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm writing a demo program to explain how to regulate the concurrency of a crowd of threads in Java, but the result is not as I expected. This is the code:

```
package parcountSyncStat;
public class Parcount extends Thread {
   private static int N=1000;
   private static Integer x=0;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       Thread[] t = new Thread[N];
       int i;
       for (i = N-1; i >= 0; i--) { 
       t[i]=new Parcount(); 
           t[i].start();
       }
       for ( i=N-1; i>=0; i-- ) t[i].join();
       System.out.println(x);
    }
    public void run() { synchronized(x) { x++; } }
}
```

In a nutshell, 1000 threads try to increment the same integer x. To preserve consistency, I encacsulate the increment in a synchronized block. The parent thread waits for all processes to finish, and then prints the final value of x, which should be 1000. But it isn't. My question is: why? I'm I wrong somewhere?

Note that I obtain the expected result by implementing a class that encapsulates the integer with a synchronized "Increment" method. But replacing the *synchronized* with a lock/unlock pair does not work either. I'm using Eclipse and did try both openjdk and oracle jdk, with similar results.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you! This is the explicit code after your suggestion, and it works correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x++` creates a new Integer object - so every time you run that statement the lock used becomes different. If you want one single lock for all you thread, create an ad hoc object:

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();
```

and synchronize on that `lock`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to assylias: here is the complete code:

```
public class Parcount extends Thread {
private static int N=1000;
private static Integer x=0;
private static final Object lock = new Object();

public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws InterruptedException {
    Thread[] t = new Thread[N];
    int i;
      for ( i=N-1; i>=0; i-- ) { 
        t[i]=new Parcount(); 
        t[i].start();
    }
    for ( i=N-1; i>=0; i-- ) t[i].join();
    System.out.println(x);
}
public void run() { synchronized(lock) { x++; } }
```

}

Comment: If someone has answered your question you should accept that answer

Answer (score -1):

The following code uses the owner of your shared resource `x`, the class `Example`, as the instance to synchronize with. You may try changing your code like this:

```
public class Example extends Thread {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread[] t = new Thread[N];
        for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            t[i] = new Example();
            t[i].start();
        }
        for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--) t[i].join();
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    private static int N = 1000;
    private static int x = 0;

    @Override public void run() {
        synchronized (Example.class) { x++; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the actual question.

Comment: Holy crap... Synchronizing on Example.class seems like a nightmare... and a terrible idea. If you get into the habit of synchronizing like this, you're going to eventually synchronize things together that you didn't want to. It'll take you hours to debug and realise you're getting deadlocks because you're synchroing on the class object. Using dedicated objects for locks is almost always the best solution

Comment: Yes Cruncher, you are right. But this was kind of exercise.