# Synchronizing a crowd in Java (part 2)

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

The question is similar to another I have just posted (and got answered). So the statement of the problem is the same:
"I'm writing a demo program to explain how to regulate the concurrency of a crowd of threads in Java, but the result is not as I expected."
This time I want to use locks, and this is the code:

```
public class Parcount extends Thread {
    private static int N=1000;
    private static int x=0;
    private final ReentrantLock l = new ReentrantLock();
    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws InterruptedException {
        Thread[] t = new Thread[N];
        int i;
        for ( i=N-1; i>=0; i-- ) { 
            t[i]=new Parcount(); 
            t[i].start();
        }
        for ( i=N-1; i>=0; i-- ) t[i].join();
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    public void run() { l.lock(); x++; l.unlock(); }
}
```

1000 threads are created, and all want to increment the x. The final printout should be 1000, but it isn't: some increments are lost. The code seems straightforward, but I probably missed something :-/

Thank you...

Comment: Your have a `ReentrantLock l` per instance of Parcount. I think you want to make it `static`.

Comment: That should be moved to an answer @NayukiMinase.

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788166/synchronizing-a-croud-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one lock for each Thread, **each Thread gets it's own lock**. You want to give one single lock per all Threads to get the proper synchronisation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the lock should have the same scope as what it is guarding, so `l` needs to be `static`, like this:

```
private static int x=0;
private static final ReentrantLock l = new ReentrantLock();
```

Note that I would probably use an `ExecutorService` to start all the threads, make `Parcount` a `Runnable` instead, make `x` and `AtomicInteger` (foregoing the need for a `ReentrantLock`), allow the number of threads to be passed as a command-line argument, and change some names to be more descriptive:

```
public class Parcount implements Runnable {

    private static final int threadCount;

    private static AtomicInteger value = new AtomicInteger();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        try { threadCount = Integer.valueOf(args[0]); } //get N as a command line argument
        catch(NumberFormatException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) { threadCount = 1000; }

        ArrayList<Callable<?>> tasks = new ArrayList<>(threadCount);

        for(int idx = 0; idx < threadCount; idx++)
            tasks.add(Executors.callable(new Parcount()));

        Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount).invokeAll(tasks);
        //no need to manually join them all: invokeAll automatically waits  

        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public void run() {
        value.getAndIncrement(); //AtomicInteger synchronizes access automatically
    }
}
```

Comment: `Scope` is more correct(and general for that matter) than `static-ness`

Comment: @Cruncher technically, they do not _need_ to have the same access modifier, although you are right that under any normal circumstance they should.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Eugene! Here following is the explicit code, according with your solution:

```
public class Parcount extends Thread {
private static int N=1000;
private static int x=0;
private static final ReentrantLock l = new ReentrantLock();
public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws InterruptedException {
    Thread[] t = new Thread[N];
    int i;
    for ( i=N-1; i>=0; i-- ) { 
        t[i]=new Parcount(); 
        t[i].start();
    }
    for ( i=N-1; i>=0; i-- ) t[i].join();
    System.out.println(x);
}
public void run() { l.lock(); x++; l.unlock(); }
```

}